# Why is my twitter login auto redirect is not working?

Tags: php, twitter

I am using twitter login for my website. In that everything works fine. The only problem i am facing now is after twitter got autheticated first time it is redirecting to my website.

But for the next time whenever i try to login using that same account it is again asking for authentication from twitter website and it is not redirecting automatically to my website if it is authenticated already.

Please help me on this. Auto redirection is working in [My Space](https://myspace.com/)

I want to integrate in that way. Please tell me what param i need to pass to oauthorize url(https://api.twitter.com/oauth/authorize) along with **oauth_token** and **callback_url**

Comment: can you post any code related to oauth?, maybe twiter api configuration?

Comment: my authorize url is similar to this - api.twitter.com/oauth/authorize?oauth_token=238ydsaiuhay8r3n&callback_url=urlencode(url)

Comment: I fixed it by myself. :)

Comment: Got fixed  by seeing this forum answer - https://dev.twitter.com/discussions/24232